# Tensor flow unknown failure

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a chat-bot using Tensorflow fallowing a tutorial, bit the same error has popped up every time.
I have tried uninstalling tensorflow and even uninstalled and reinstalled python but this error show up:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:98: The name tf.AUTO_REUSE is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:98: The name tf.AttrValue is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.AttrValue instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:98: The name tf.COMPILER_VERSION is deprecated. Please use tf.version.COMPILER_VERSION instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:98: The name tf.CXX11_ABI_FLAG is deprecated. Please use tf.sysconfig.CXX11_ABI_FLAG instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:98: The name tf.ConditionalAccumulator is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ConditionalAccumulator instead.
```

I am using python 3.7.3
here is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJDEOWLHYVo

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add some more details, like the tutorial you have been using and some relevant code. Also refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions. Btw. the lines you have posted show warning, not errors, does your code work? Maybe the tutorial is outdated, because if something is deprecated, that means it has been replaced by new functionality and should not be used anymore.

Comment: interesting. it is actually not working because when i use another file to try to download "data_utils" it does not work and i am pretty sure that the main file is not working.the video was made in 2016 so its a few years old i will try to find an updated tutorial. thanks so much.